# How to use X such that certain input modifies the output of other input?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, xorg

What I want to do is, for example, press and hold mouse button 4, and then press mouse button 5, and have this pass a different input [like a keyboard keypress or some other mouse button] to a program.

The purpose is, if I have a mouse with N keys, this will allow me to emulate having 2*(N-1) inputs from my mouse, which will allow me to play videogames with only my mouse, which would normally require a mouse and keyboard or a mouse with more buttons than mine.

I'm using cinnamon desktop on linux. And I expect the way to do this might be to have mouse4 run some program that changes key bindings. If it's not possible to have a program execute on button release I don't mind having to press mouse4 a second time to toggle back to default layout. I found this is possible on keyboard [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension#Multiple_layouts), but I can't find any information about doing this with a mouse.

A direct answer would be amazing, but any hints that might point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: im new to stack exchange, i just realized i probably should have put this on the linux/unix exchange, rather than here. i assume doubleposting is discouraged. is there an easy way to transfer this from here to there, other than deleting and reposting, or am i likely to get an answer here?